# Cannot use commands write mode error, Degrading to compatibility mode

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I just play with mongo shell and came across with `Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode`.

I connected to remote mongo server (mongolab) and tried to insert new record to collection by my simple script:

```
// script.js
db = connect(host + ":" + port +"/" + dbName);
db.auth(username, password);

db.test2.insert({ item: "card", qty: 15 });
```

I run script by `mongo script.js` and got:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
connecting to: my.mongolab.com:port/DBname
Cannot use commands write mode, degrading to compatibility mode
```

What is wrong? Additionally when I executed similar query after connected via `mongo my.mongolab.com:port/DBname -u <dbuser> -p <dbpassword>` everything is OK.

Comment: You are connecting to a MongoDB instance that is a lower version than 2.6. Not likely to be of much more future benefit to people as this will go away over time. It's just a warning and does not "generally" affect operations.

Comment: @NeilLunn thank's. In fact record was inserted. I didn't notice that, sorry. But what about production environment, can I ignore this warning?

Comment: @NHG You can always download the correct version (according to `db.version()`) from http://www.mongodb.org/ e.g. https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.7.tgz

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are using a shell that's newer than the server it's communicating with.

You can check the server version from the shell via `db.version()` - to check shell version you use `version()`

Starting with 2.6 the mongod server started using new write commands which are different than the previously use insert/update/remove op code (this is all described in the [MongoDB Wire Protocol](http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/)).

This is a harmless "informational" warning.  It's a good idea to use the same version shell as the server to avoid wondering about such things though.