# MongoDB error: Cannot use 'commands' readMode, degrading to 'legacy' mode

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

So I was developing a project using mongo and I got an error after executing the code:
`db.usercollection.insert({ "username" : "testuser1", "email" : "testuser1@testdomain.com" })`

The error displayed was:

```
Cannot use 'commands' readMode, degrading to 'legacy' mode WriteResult({
        "writeError" : {
                "code" : 13,
                "errmsg" : "not authorized on watersheds to execute command { insert: \"usercollection\", documents: [ { _id: ObjectId('568d0eda45d472b121116bef'), username: \"testuser1\", email: \"testuser1@testdomain.com\" } ], ordered: true }"
        } })
```

The db.version() is 3.0.7 and I installed MongoDB shell version is 3.2.0

How should I fix this?

Regards,
Daryll

Comment: restart the mongo shell and issue db.getMongo().forceReadMode("legacy") or 
db.getMongo().forceReadMode("compatibility") command.

Comment: Your shell and DB versions probably aren't the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916320/cannot-use-commands-write-mode-error-degrading-to-compatibility-mode

Answer (score 3):

```
db.getCollection(collectionName).count({});
db.getCollection(collectionName).find({});
```

It works! maybe mongo needs other operation.

Answer (score 2):

I just restart the mongod process instead and works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Buzut's comment above...

I just ran into this same error. For me, the issue was a version difference between the client running locally and the version of the mongo db running in the cloud.

To verify if that's your issue, run `mongo --version` locally and take note of the version number. Then connect to your mongo db shell and run `db.version()` to check the version there.

If there is a major difference in those numbers (like a version 3 client and a version 2 db), you'll likely need to switch to client version that's closer to your db version.

To do that, go the Mongo download center: https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#production

Select your platform, then click on 'All Version Binaries', and look for a download that matches your hosted db.

That will download a compressed file that you'll need to unpack. And inside there will be a folder. Simply use the path to the /bin/mongo executable (inside that folder) to execute your mongo commands. For example:

`/path/to/downloads/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.6.9/bin/mongo <whatever mongo commands you want>`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! They removed the 3.0.x set up instructions from their documentation, and instead added a nice disclaimer that the documentation is no longer maintained. I couldn't figure out how to download the older version.  I really need to just update my mongo version on mLab but have been putting it off fearing it would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are a victim of having `replica set` and lost `Primary db` or not.
If so, recreate the Primary one or use this command before your insertion.

```
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk();
```

Answer (score -2):

Cannot use `'commands' readMode`, degrading to `legacy mode`,

```
rs-ds017231:PRIMARY> show dbs

rs-ds017231:PRIMARY> db

rs-ds017231:PRIMARY>db.collection_name.insert({})
```

It works for me !